# How can I poupulate a hidden form field with a value from a dropdown?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I have these:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    getRequestCategories();

    $('#requestCategory').change(function() {
        getRequestDescriptions( $(this).val() );
    });
});


function getRequestCategories() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'getCategories.php',
        dataType: 'json'
    })
    .done(function(categoryInfo) {
        $(categoryInfo).each(function(i, category) {
            $('<option>').val(category.RequestCategoryDisplay).text(category.RequestCategoryDisplay).appendTo( $('#requestCategory') );
        })
    });
}


function getRequestDescriptions(requestCategory) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'getDescriptions.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { requestCategory: requestCategory }
    })
    .done(function(descriptionInfo) {
        $(descriptionInfo).each(function(i, description) {
            $('<option>').val(description.RequestDescriptionDisplay).text(description.RequestDescriptionDisplay).appendTo( $('#description') );
        })
    });
}



         Category
          <select name="requestCategory" id="Category" style="width:250px;font-size:10pt;"  class="changeable" data-summary="summCategory">
           <option value=""></option>
          </select>
        Description
         <select name="description" id="description" style="width:250px;font-size:10pt;"  class="changeable" data-summary="summSubCategory">
      <option value=""></option>
     </select>
```

How it works currently:

When you select a value from the `Category` dropdown, all the values associated with your selection are automatically into the `description` dropdown.

This works fine.

However, we have a new requirement to populate the following hidden form field with user's selection from the `description` dropdown:

```
  <input name="RequestID" id="RequestID" type="text"  width="300" value=""  class="changeable" />
```

In other words, once the `description` dropdown is populated with values based on selection from `Category` dropdown, then when a user selects one of the values from the `description` dropdown, the accompanying value of RequestID should be saved into a hidden form field.

I tried modifying the getDescriptions function but I am not getting the correct values.

Each value I select from the description dropdown gives me same values for RequestID.

Can you please see what I am doing wrong?

Thanks so much in advance.

```
        function getDescriptions(requestCategory) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'getDescriptions.php',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: { requestCategory: requestCategory }
            })
            .done(function(descriptionInfo) {

            // get number of items in array given by php
            var Desc_count = descriptionInfo.length;

            // loop request descriptions
            for (var i = 0; i < Desc_count; i += 1) {

                // append an <option> tag to your <select>
                $('#description').append('<option value="' + descriptionInfo[i].RequestID + '">' + descriptionInfo[i].RequestDescriptionDisplay + '</option>');
            }

            // Listen for the value of the <select> to change
            $('#description').on('change', function () {
                // get the value of the selected option ,the value is the descriptionInfo[i].RequestID
                var value = $( "#description option:selected").val();
               // Set the value of the hidden fields based on the <select>'s ID choosing the corret array element
                $('input[name="RequestID"]').val(value);
            });
        });
}
```

Comment: Try moving the "change listener" outside the function after the requestCategory change listener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very strange this isnt working.. is your on change event happening in $(document).ready()  ?

I try to help:

instad of your  `$('#description').on('change', function () {` event try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#description').change(function() { 
       $('#RequestID').val($(this).val());
    });
});
```

if this doesnt work try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#description').live('change', function() { 
       $('#RequestID').val($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried both of your codes but still getting same thing, unless I am using it incorrectly.

Wilmer, I am not sure I follow, sorry.

Thanks to you two for your responses.

Comment: Can you try running it through a javascript check? like.. www.jslint.com. I'm not sure why its not working - is your console showing any error in chrome/firefox?  maybe a syntax error somewhere.. if you can make a Fiddle that would be perfect.

Comment: I can't fiddle it because 1, it is internal, 2) so many different dependent pieces.

However, I have inspected it and no errors.

And it is producing results, just like mine is, just not the correct results.

For instance, there are 5 categories. Of these categories, only one has a value like this: null,null, null, null, null, 'Cataract'.

So, first time you select from the categories that have no values, it doesn't display anything. THis is good. Then you select from the one that has value, it displays the values I showed. Now, you go back to those without values, they start to...

Comment: I ran out space. I was going to say, initially those without values display no values as they should. You click on the one with values and it displays 5 nulls and one actual value called `cataract`.

Now, you go back to click the ones that are not supposed to have values, they begin to show same values,  5 nulls and `cataract`. You click it again, the values double, like null, null, null, null, null, `cataract`, null, null, null, null, null, `cataract`. I think you get the idea. 

Just need to show values for the only one that has it.

Comment: oh... so your change event is working?? wow i totally misunderstood your problem..  you should clear your select then if it is keeping old values... at start of getDescriptions `function getDescriptions(requestCategory) {  $('#description option').remove(); .....` 
if I am still mis-understanding your problem please provide more code.. as much as you can. even a quick mockup in a jsfiddle.. doesnt have to be actual code.. just an example.

Comment: @JFTit.

This is perfect. It is working great now.

Thanks very much for all your help.